# Autocomplete + dropdownlist +primefaces

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

Very new to primefaces, so please forgive me if it is easy one.

As I want to clear autocomplete textboxes while changing value in drop down.

In my xhtml page, when i select company from drop down the bank associated with that country will come. when i took bank, branch associated with that bank will come in next autocomplete field.That was working fine.

But when i took next country that autocomplete fields are not getting cleared.

please help me to resolve this.

This div is drop down list for country

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="grid4 bordered-box">
        <p:outputLabel styleClass="col4 mandatory-field" value="#{msg['Label.CountryList']}" /> 
        <div class="col5">
            <p:selectOneMenu   id="countryList" style="width: 10px ; border:1px #DDDBDB solid ;background-color: #F4EDC1;" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"  required="true" 
                               value="#{bankBranchController.bankBranchDetails.countryCode}">
                <p:ajax process="@this" update="bankDD"  />
                <f:selectItems
                    value="#{bankBranchController.countryList}"
                    var="item" itemLabel="#{item.label}"
                    itemValue="#{item.value}" />
                <f:selectItems/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This div is for autocomplete for Bank

```
<div class="grid4 bordered-box">
    <p:outputLabel styleClass="col4 mandatory-field" value=" Bank " /> 
    <div class="col5">                           
        <p:autoComplete  id="bankDD" minQueryLength="3" value="#{bankBranchController.bankBranchDetails.bankName}" completeMethod="#{bankBranchController.getBankListAutoComplete}"
                         var="varItem" itemLabel="#{varItem.label}" itemValue="#{varItem.value}" scrollHeight="120" >
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="branchDD"></p:ajax>

        </p:autoComplete>      
    </div>
</div>
```

This div is for autocomplete for branch

```
<div class="col5">
    <p:autoComplete  id="branchDD" minQueryLength="3" value="#{bankBranchController.bankBranchDetails.bankBranchName}" 
                     completeMethod="#{bankBranchController.getBankBranchListAutoComplete}"
                     var="item" itemLabel="#{item.label}" itemValue="#{item.value}" scrollHeight="120" >      
    </p:autoComplete>                               
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add listener method in `<p:ajax process="@this" update="bankDD" />`, and in that method you should `bankBranchDetails.setBankName("")` or even `bankBranchDetails = new BankBranchDetails()`, anyway it should be cleared.

Comment: I wrote the same, <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bankBranchController.resetBranch()}"/> on that country drop down. and in that resetBranch,bankBranchDetails.setBankName("").But it causes error as "The class 'java.lang.string' does not have the property 'label'

Comment: It's correct, your autocomplete's completeMethod return list of strings, and you want to use `var="item" itemLabel="#{item.label}" itemValue="#{item.value}"` but `java.lang.String` does not have neither getLabel(), nor getValue() methods... And this is another problem.

Comment: so any other solution?

Comment: Am... What? It is not a problem, just fix your `<p:autoComplete...` by removing var, itemLabel and itemValue attributes...